# Bash map not giving proper result

Tags: bash, dictionary

I am using map in bash as follows:

```
declare -a hash
hash=(["a"]="A" ["b"]="B" ["c"]="C" ["d"]="D")

echo ${hash["a"]}
```

https://ideone.com/YfnazQ

However it is printing `D` instead of `A`. What's is the issue in this snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is just how you defined the variable hash.

`declare -a hash` is for indexed arrays, I mean, arrays where the index is just numbers.

To declare an associative array, just change -a for -A:

`declare -A hash`

That way you can write letters as the index, and that echo will work as expected.

Hope I helped!

Comment: -bash: declare: -A: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]

Comment: @ShashwatKumar What version of bash are you using? It works for me in 4.2.46, I`ve just tried it.

Comment: It was 3.2. After updating it changed to 5.0.7

Comment: Still looking. new bash path is /usr/local/bin/bash but /bin/bash still points to 3.2 version. I want /bin/bash to be 5.0.7

Comment: @ShashwatKumar Maybe [this](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=659655&seqNum=3) can help you with it. Remember to log out and log in again after change it

Comment: Hi @ShashwatKumar, did you managed to do it? Can we help you any more with it?

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake or typo, you specified key `-a` instead of `-A`

So instead:

```sh
declare -a hash
```

use:

```
declare -A hash
```